# Debugging Animation performance in Chrome

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I am having performance issues in a React app I am working on. A page is taking a lot of time to render. On profiling the page using `Performance` tab in Chrome, I found that some animations are taking a lot of time (16.52 seconds!). But I am not able to figure out which part in my code is causing this issue? Here are the screenshots for recorded performance.

[image: Animations is taking 16.52 seconds to run]

[image: Is this the call stack?]

Can anyone point to a good resource on how to debug this? [Google's page on debugging performance](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/evaluate-performance/reference) is not very helpful for above scenario.